# Validate 'Could not resolve host' use case in Postman

Tags: postman, saas, postman-collection-runner

I need to delete a tenant and make sure that the tenant is not accessible anymore. Is there a way to validate 'Could not resolve host' i.e. 'Error: getaddrinfo' in Postman as this error is the expected behavior?

When below curl command is executed in a terminal

> curl https://invaliddomain1281738012732.com -v

Proper error message is displayed

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: invaliddomain1281738012732.com

But in postman, is there a way to add a test to validate this behavior?
[image: Postman Error: getaddrinfo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to test the validity of the URL by calling it directly and writing a test on the result, from [Postman's Learning Center](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/):

> Tests will execute after the response is received, so when you click
> Send, Postman will run your test script when the response data returns
> from the API.

A workaround to that is to query that URL directly from the Tests tab and assert the response there, e.g.:

```
pm.test("address doesn't exist", function(){
    pm.sendRequest('https://invaliddomain1281738012732.com', (error, response) => {
        pm.expect(error.errno).to.eql("ENOTFOUND");
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Arlemi for the solution, I have added this as a test for 'Delete tenant request' call.